Next.Js Fallback Routes
I make my first steps with Next.Js. I am using version 14.
I read "Create a loading state by adding a loading.js file inside a folder." here
https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/loading-ui-and-streaming
I read "Create error UI by adding an error.js file inside a route segment and exporting a React component:" here:
https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/error-handling
My directory tree is shown in the attached picture.

The code for my detail page /src/app/campdays/[campdayId]/page.tsx is this:
import clsx from "clsx";
import { Heading } from "@/components/heading";
import { Placeholder } from "@/components/placeholder";
import { CampdayItem } from "@/features/campday/components/campday-item";
import { getCampday } from "@/features/campday/queries/get-campday";

type CampdayPageProps = {
  params: {
    campdayId: string;
  };
};

const CampdayDetailPage = async ({ params }: CampdayPageProps) => {
  const campday = await getCampday(params.campdayId);

  if (!campday) {
    return <Placeholder label="Campday not found" />;
  }

  return <div className="p-20 flex-1 flex flex-col gap-y-8">

    <Heading
      title={campday.title}
      description="About the project"
    />

    <div className="flex-1 flex flex-col items-center animate-fade-in-from-top">
      <div
        className={clsx("text-sm text-slate-500 truncate", {
          "line-through": campday.status === "CLOSE",
        })}
      >

        <CampdayItem campday={campday} isDetail />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>;
}

export default CampdayDetailPage;

I simulate an error for testing in /src/features/campday/queries/get-campday.ts
import { initialCampdays } from "@/data";
import { Campday } from "../types";

export const getCampday = async (id: string): Promise<Campday | null> => {
  await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 2000));

  //throw new Error("Oops!");

  const maybeCampday = initialCampdays.find((campday) => String(campday.id) === id);

  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    resolve(maybeCampday || null);
  });
};

I expect the error to be skipped when calling up the detail page and the src/app/campdays/[campdayId]/error.tsx  file to be displayed.
However, the file is not used at all.
src/app/campdays/[campdayId]/error.tsx 
"use client";

export default function Error({ error }: { error: Error }) {
  return <div>{error.message ?? "Something went wrong!"}</div>;
}

The src/app/campdays/[campdayId]/loading.tsx  is also not used.
src/app/campdays/[campdayId]/loading.tsx 
export default function Loading() {
    return <div>Loading...</div>
}

I suspect that I configured something wrong. But what?
